# After changing my router I get very high ping in my friends servers

Tags: networking, router, lan, hamachi

After changing my router from a very old one, which also changed my connection from 2.4Ghz to 5ghz connection, I have run into this issue. The issue is that whenever we play games from steam that I need to join them, I get very high ping and vice versa. I believe it might be some configuration that I might need to change from my new router? Please help, anything is appreciated. We have also tried to use hamachi or other alternatives and the same issue occurs.

WINMTR results:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

|                                      WinMTR statistics               |

|                       Host              -   %  | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |

|------------------------------------------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|

|                             192.168.0.1 -    0 |  777 |  777 |    1 |    4 |  150 |    2 |

|                              10.36.64.1 -    0 |  777 |  777 |    5 |   14 |  157 |   10 |

|                            10.242.2.201 -    0 |  777 |  777 |    5 |   15 |  162 |    8 |

|                            10.242.3.170 -    0 |  777 |  777 |    5 |   15 |  166 |   11 |

|                            10.242.3.169 -    6 |  642 |  608 |    6 |   16 |  245 |   11 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|                   No response from host -  100 |  156 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |

|________________________________________________|______|______|______|______|______|______|
```

WinMTR v0.92 GPL V2 by Appnor MSP - Fully Managed Hosting & Cloud Provider

Comment: 4ghz connection?  Run WinMTR or similar and report back with its reported latencies and packet loss.  Does the problem go away if you use an Ethernet cable?  What are the makes and models of the old and new routers?

Comment: How should i send you the results? i saved it as a .txt file. btw thanks for trying to help me out i really appreciate it

Comment: Copy and paste them into the question. Then leave a comment here so I know to respond.

Comment: Okay, i did it.

Comment: You have a weird setup I don't fully understand.  How are you and your friends connected?

Comment: Emm im not sure, i just copied his IP in to the software and ran the test for a while, should i have done something different?

Comment: I think the IP address you used for him is not his external IP address, so stuff is looping around in the ISP and timing out - but it doesn't matter, I believe I have the info I need.  I'm putting an answer together for you.

Comment: Check the MTU values used by your network adapter and the two routers.

Answer (score 0):

(It is possible you might have more then 1 issue, but )

Your MTR result shows that you have congestion between yourself and your router.  If you look at the Wrst vs Best result you have no packet loss, but very variable latency.   These are hallmarks of a mildly congested WIFI network - so this is where you should focus your attention.

First off - If you are after the lowest possible ping, ditch the WIFI and plug in an ethernet cable.   This will eliminate WIFI as a source of interference.   If your gaming is not that sensitive or crucial, you can likely improve your WIFI.   Everything below this is educated speculation.

If you are using 5gig connectivity (which you indicate), I suspect you may be to far from your router.  5 gig connectivity is generally faster then 2.4 gig connectivity if you are close to the router, but has a much shorter range.  If you can move your computer closer to the router, do it.    Likewise, if there are obstacles between your computer and the router, if you can eliminate them it will help.

Alternatively, try connecting on the 2.4 gig band and see if that helps.

Something else to look at (which is more applicable to 2.4 then 5 gig band, but does apply to both) is what other devices are broadcasting/listening.  WIFI is a shared medium, so if you have lots of people or lots of traffic using it, try reduce the amount of traffic using your WIFI - in your case I expect this will help.   If your neighbours are using WIFI as well, make sure you select different NON OVERLAPPING channels for your WIFI.  On 2.4 gig band these are typically channels 1, 6 and 11.      If you have an android phone, you can download a WIFI analyzer tool which can help assess signal strength and channel utilization.

It is, of-course, possible that your WIFI router is not great.   There are very large differences in quality of different types of equipment.  If the problem is software related (but I don't think it is here), flashing dd-wrt on a router can make a big difference to performance if your router supports it.  It can also help with traffic management by deploying QoS - which could allow you to give your game priority bandwidth.

Comment: Just noticed I called the 2.4 gig band 4ghz my bad. Thanks for the answer, but I would like to add some more info. My internet connection is the best I have had yet, although still pretty bad but this is all I can get for now. I have really low ping in most games (around 30) but the issue lays in when trying to join a game through LAN (I think it's called that) so I'm actually joining my friends server and I'm really laggy. This happens to me with several friends that before I was able to play smoothly. Edit forgot to add some things: I cant use an ethernet cable since the router is kind of-

Comment: far away and i cant really do it for other reasons. Also, i have tried using the 2.4 gig band and connecting to my friends servers is the same or even more laggy, when before changing the router it was smooth. Could it be some configuration of the new router?

Comment: The problem is not with your friends, its with the bandwidth available between your WIFI router and your computer.  What router do you have and what are its WiFi settings? Does it support 80 and/or 160 mhz channels? If so, increasing the channel width can give you more bandwidth - which can decrease the latency caused by congestion.